# How do I launch a VS Plugin via Powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I need to automatically start Visual Studio and then an extension someone has written ages ago that reads an excel file and processes it. 
My idea was to launch Visual Studio via PowerShell and then the PlugIn when VS is running. I have never written a .vsix file and I'm not sure whether there is a way to start an extension from the console. I stumbled across the 'Invoke-Item' cmdlet that I thought could do what I need, but can't find any sort of executable that launches the Plugin.

Alternatively, could I give a  series of commands to PowerShell to to launch the PlugIn from the Extensions tab?

This is what I already have to launch VS.

```
$path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("ProgramFilesX86"); #Finde ProgramFiles auf dem Rechner
$pathCom = $path + "\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\" #VS Community Pfad
$pathPro = $path + "\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\" #VS Professional Pfad

$ar = Get-Process -Name devenv -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$ar){
    Write-Host "Locating Visual Studio in $path"

    if(![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($pathCom)){

        if(![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($pathPro)){

            echo "Could not locate Visual studio. Terminating..."
            exit
        }
        else {
            $path = $pathPro;
        }
    }
    else {
        $path = $pathCom;
    }
    Write-Host "Found Visual Studio in $path."
    Write-Host "Starting Visual Studio..."
    $exe = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -File -Filter 'devenv.exe'

    $path += $exe
    & "$path"
}
else{
    Write-Host "Visual Studio not started; already running."
}
Remove-Variable ar
```